# Error with SQL Server Setup 2012 on Windows 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, sql-server-2012

I am trying to install SQL Server on Windows 2012. I was able to finally get the wizard up and running after making some changes on the server, but now it fails no matter what I do with the following error:

> ### TITLE: SQL Server Setup failure.
>
> SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:
>
> There is an error in XML document (108, 148)..
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&EvtType=0x066FCAFD%25400x5539C151

```
LinkID: 20476
Product Name: Microsoft SQL Server
Message Source setup.rll
Message ID: 50000
EvtType: 0x066FCAFD%400x5539C151
```

What I've tried:

Installing from commandline with /q

Result from CL  installation:

> Error result: -2147467259 Result facility code: 0 Result error code:
>   16389
>
> Please review the summary.txt log for further details

The Verbose CL installation reveals:

```
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_bids_loc.msi' does not exist
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_bids_loc.msi' does not exist
Package ID sql_bids_loc_Cpu64_1033: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1036_FRA_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_bids_loc.msi' does not exist
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1036_FRA_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_bids_loc.msi' does not exist
Package ID sql_bids_loc_Cpu64_1036: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1040_ITA_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_bids_loc.msi' does not exist
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1040_ITA_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_bids_loc.msi' does not exist
Package ID sql_bids_loc_Cpu64_1040: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1041_JPN_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_bids_loc.msi' does not exist
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1041_JPN_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_bids_loc.msi' does not exist
Package ID sql_bids_loc_Cpu64_1041: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1042_KOR_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_bids_loc.msi' does not exist
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1042_KOR_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_bids_loc.msi' does not exist
Package ID sql_bids_loc_Cpu64_1042: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1046_PTB_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_bids_loc.msi' does not exist
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1046_PTB_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_bids_loc.msi' does not exist
Package ID sql_bids_loc_Cpu64_1046: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1049_RUS_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_bids_loc.msi' does not exist
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1049_RUS_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_bids_loc.msi' does not exist
Package ID sql_bids_loc_Cpu64_1049: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\2052_CHS_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_bids_loc.msi' does not exist
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\2052_CHS_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_bids_loc.msi' does not exist
Package ID sql_bids_loc_Cpu64_2052: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\3082_ESN_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_bids_loc.msi' does not exist
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\3082_ESN_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_bids_loc.msi' does not exist
Package ID sql_bids_loc_Cpu64_3082: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1053_SVE_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_bids_loc.msi' does not exist
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1053_SVE_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_bids_loc.msi' does not exist
Package ID sql_bids_loc_Cpu64_1053: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\x64\setup\x64\sql_ssms.msi' does not exist
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\x64\setup\x64\sql_ssms.msi' does not exist
Package ID sql_ssms_Cpu64: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1028_CHT_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_ssms_loc.msi' does not exist
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1028_CHT_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_ssms_loc.msi' does not exist
Package ID sql_ssms_loc_Cpu64_1028: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1031_DEU_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_ssms_loc.msi' does not exist
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1031_DEU_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_ssms_loc.msi' does not exist
Package ID sql_ssms_loc_Cpu64_1031: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_ssms_loc.msi' does not exist
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_ssms_loc.msi' does not exist
Package ID sql_ssms_loc_Cpu64_1033: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1036_FRA_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_ssms_loc.msi' does not exist
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1036_FRA_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_ssms_loc.msi' does not exist
Package ID sql_ssms_loc_Cpu64_1036: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1040_ITA_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_ssms_loc.msi' does not exist
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1040_ITA_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_ssms_loc.msi' does not exist
Package ID sql_ssms_loc_Cpu64_1040: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1041_JPN_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_ssms_loc.msi' does not exist
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1041_JPN_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_ssms_loc.msi' does not exist
Package ID sql_ssms_loc_Cpu64_1041: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1042_KOR_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_ssms_loc.msi' does not exist
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1042_KOR_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_ssms_loc.msi' does not exist
Package ID sql_ssms_loc_Cpu64_1042: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1046_PTB_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_ssms_loc.msi' does not exist
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1046_PTB_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_ssms_loc.msi' does not exist
Package ID sql_ssms_loc_Cpu64_1046: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1049_RUS_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_ssms_loc.msi' does not exist
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1049_RUS_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_ssms_loc.msi' does not exist
Package ID sql_ssms_loc_Cpu64_1049: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\2052_CHS_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_ssms_loc.msi' does not exist
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\2052_CHS_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_ssms_loc.msi' does not exist
Package ID sql_ssms_loc_Cpu64_2052: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\3082_ESN_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_ssms_loc.msi' does not exist
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\3082_ESN_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_ssms_loc.msi' does not exist
Package ID sql_ssms_loc_Cpu64_3082: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1053_SVE_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_ssms_loc.msi' does not exist
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1053_SVE_LP\x64\setup\x64\sql_ssms_loc.msi' does not exist
Package ID sql_ssms_loc_Cpu64_1053: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\x64\setup\sql_common_core_msi\x64\sql_common_core.msi' does not e
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\x64\setup\sql_common_core_msi\x64\sql_common_core.msi' does not e
Package ID sql_common_core_Cpu64: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1028_CHT_LP\x64\setup\sql_common_core_loc_msi\x64\sql_common_core
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1028_CHT_LP\x64\setup\sql_common_core_loc_msi\x64\sql_common_core
Package ID sql_common_core_loc_Cpu64_1028: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1031_DEU_LP\x64\setup\sql_common_core_loc_msi\x64\sql_common_core
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1031_DEU_LP\x64\setup\sql_common_core_loc_msi\x64\sql_common_core
Package ID sql_common_core_loc_Cpu64_1031: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\sql_common_core_loc_msi\x64\sql_common_core
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\sql_common_core_loc_msi\x64\sql_common_core
Package ID sql_common_core_loc_Cpu64_1033: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1036_FRA_LP\x64\setup\sql_common_core_loc_msi\x64\sql_common_core
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1036_FRA_LP\x64\setup\sql_common_core_loc_msi\x64\sql_common_core
Package ID sql_common_core_loc_Cpu64_1036: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1040_ITA_LP\x64\setup\sql_common_core_loc_msi\x64\sql_common_core
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1040_ITA_LP\x64\setup\sql_common_core_loc_msi\x64\sql_common_core
Package ID sql_common_core_loc_Cpu64_1040: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1041_JPN_LP\x64\setup\sql_common_core_loc_msi\x64\sql_common_core
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1041_JPN_LP\x64\setup\sql_common_core_loc_msi\x64\sql_common_core
Package ID sql_common_core_loc_Cpu64_1041: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1042_KOR_LP\x64\setup\sql_common_core_loc_msi\x64\sql_common_core
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1042_KOR_LP\x64\setup\sql_common_core_loc_msi\x64\sql_common_core
Package ID sql_common_core_loc_Cpu64_1042: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1046_PTB_LP\x64\setup\sql_common_core_loc_msi\x64\sql_common_core
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1046_PTB_LP\x64\setup\sql_common_core_loc_msi\x64\sql_common_core
Package ID sql_common_core_loc_Cpu64_1046: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1049_RUS_LP\x64\setup\sql_common_core_loc_msi\x64\sql_common_core
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1049_RUS_LP\x64\setup\sql_common_core_loc_msi\x64\sql_common_core
Package ID sql_common_core_loc_Cpu64_1049: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\2052_CHS_LP\x64\setup\sql_common_core_loc_msi\x64\sql_common_core
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\2052_CHS_LP\x64\setup\sql_common_core_loc_msi\x64\sql_common_core
Package ID sql_common_core_loc_Cpu64_2052: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\3082_ESN_LP\x64\setup\sql_common_core_loc_msi\x64\sql_common_core
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\3082_ESN_LP\x64\setup\sql_common_core_loc_msi\x64\sql_common_core
Package ID sql_common_core_loc_Cpu64_3082: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1053_SVE_LP\x64\setup\sql_common_core_loc_msi\x64\sql_common_core
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1053_SVE_LP\x64\setup\sql_common_core_loc_msi\x64\sql_common_core
Package ID sql_common_core_loc_Cpu64_1053: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\SQL Server 2012\Setup\1033_ENU_LP\x6
lSupport.msi' does not exist
Sco: File 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\SQL Server 2012\Setup\1033_ENU_LP\x6
lSupport.msi' does not exist
Package ID SqlSupport_Cpu64: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\redist\watson\x86\dw20shared.msi' does not exist
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\redist\watson\x86\dw20shared.msi' does not exist
Package ID WatsonX86_Cpu32: NotInstalled
Package ID sqlncli_Cpu64: NotInstalled
Package ID SqlLocalDB_Cpu64: NotInstalled
Package ID SqlLocalDB_CTP3_Cpu64: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\x86\SSDTStub.msi' does not exist
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\x86\SSDTStub.msi' does not exist
Package ID SSDTStub_Cpu32: NotInstalled
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\x86\SSDTDBSvcExternals.msi' does not exist
Sco: File 'C:\SQL Install\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\x86\SSDTDBSvcExternals.msi' does not exist
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of banging my head against my desk I got it installed. SQL Server 2012 on Windows Server 2012 is a bit fragile (at the time of writting).

What I had to do was very simple: Re download the install file from Microsoft.com. When you get errors that MSI files are missing (and they are still there), start over. Redownload the installation media.